# gcc auto-vectorisation (unhandled data-ref)

Tags: gcc, openmp, auto-vectorization

I do not understand why such code is not vectorized with gcc 4.4.6

```
int MyFunc(const float *pfTab, float *pfResult, int iSize, int iIndex)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
     pfResult[i] = pfResult[i] + pfTab[iIndex];
}

 note: not vectorized: unhandled data-ref
```

However, if I write the following code

```
   int MyFunc(const float *pfTab, float *pfResult, int iSize, int iIndex)
{
  float fTab =  pfTab[iIndex];
  for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
     pfResult[i] = pfResult[i] + fTab;
}
```

gcc succeeds auto-vectorize this loop

if I add omp directive

```
   int MyFunc(const float *pfTab, float *pfResult, int iSize, int iIndex)
{
  float fTab =  pfTab[iIndex];
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
     pfResult[i] = pfResult[i] + fTab;
}
```

i have the following error not vectorized: unhandled data-ref

Could you please help me why the first code and third code is not auto-vectorized ?

Second question:
math operand seems to be not vectorized (exp, log , etc...), this code for example

```
for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
         pfResult[i] = exp(pfResult[i]);
```

is not vectorized. It is due to my version of gcc ?

**Edit**:
 with new version of gcc 4.8.1 and openMP 2011 (echo |cpp -fopenmp -dM |grep -i open)
i have the following error for all kind of loop even basically

```
   for (iGID = 0; iGID < iSize; iGID++)
        {
             pfResult[iGID] = fValue;
        }


note: not consecutive access *_144 = 5.0e-1;
note: Failed to SLP the basic block.
note: not vectorized: failed to find SLP opportunities in basic block.
```

Edit2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
        int szGlobalWorkSize = 131072;
        int iGID = 0;
        int j = 0;
        omp_set_dynamic(0);
        // warmup
        #if WARMUP
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
        #pragma omp master
        {
        printf("%d threads\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }
        }
        #endif
        printf("Pagesize=%d\n", getpagesize());
        float *pfResult = (float *)malloc(szGlobalWorkSize * 100* sizeof(float));
        float fValue = 0.5f;
        struct timeval tim;
        gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
        double tLaunch1=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);
        double time = omp_get_wtime();
        int iChunk = getpagesize();
        int iSize = ((int)szGlobalWorkSize * 100) / iChunk;
        //#pragma omp parallel for
        for (iGID = 0; iGID < iSize; iGID++)
        {
             pfResult[iGID] = fValue;
        }
        time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
        gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
        double tLaunch2=tim.tv_sec+(tim.tv_usec/1000000.0);
        printf("%.6lf Time1\n", tLaunch2-tLaunch1);
        printf("%.6lf Time2\n", time);
}
```

result with

```
#define _OPENMP 201107
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

gcc -march=native -fopenmp -O3 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 test.c -lm
```

lot of

```
note: Failed to SLP the basic block.
note: not vectorized: failed to find SLP opportunities in basic block.
and note: not consecutive access *_144 = 5.0e-1;
```

Thanks

Comment: First thing would indeed be to try a more recent version of gcc. Then realize that without `restrict` vectorization could be wrong. And add -ffast-math because the compiler is scared otherwise. For exp and log, I'm sure I've seen related questions on SO. Basically, you would need to have a library that provides vector versions of exp and log so gcc could generate calls to them.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment, why aren't you using `i` in your loops???

Comment: thanks a lot
I have already tried with '__restrict__' and const and the result is the same
I will try with more recent version of gcc 
sorry for the typo loop

Comment: i have installed gcc 4.8.1 and now all my loop gives the following information
note: Failed to SLP the basic block.
note: not vectorized: failed to find SLP opportunities in basic block.

Comment: SLP is about vectorizing things that are **not** loops, you are probably looking at the wrong dump/log.

Comment: no, i have edit my first post, even with a simple loop vector = value(0.05) , output corresponds exactly to the line of the loop and there are hundreds time the same kind of output

Comment: gcc-4.8.3 -O3 -fopenmp vectorizes your examples 1 and 3. It is too hard to reproduce your issue so I can't help, sorry.

Comment: thanks a lot, could you please test my Edit2 code on your gcc and tell me your output of my gcc command ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (missing headers?), that's just rude. There are online compilers available if you want to test your code without installing anything.

Comment: Also, just because plenty of things don't vectorize doesn't mean you don't have somewhere hidden in there: "vectorized 1 loops in function.", and you only need one of those.

Comment: headers added, indeed I have "vectorized 1 loops in function" but at the line corresponding to main(), i find that you have too much information with gcc 4.8 it is not very clear now, Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC cannot vectorise the first version of your loop because it cannot prove that `pfTab[iIndex]` is not contained somewhere within the memory spanned by `pfResult[0] ... pfResult[iSize-1]` (pointer aliasing). Indeed, if `pfTab[iIndex]` is somewhere within that memory, then its value must be overwritten by the assignment in the loop body and the new value must be used in the iterations to follow. You should use the `restrict` keyword to hint the compiler that this could never happen and then it should happily vectorise your code:

```
$ cat foo.c
int MyFunc(const float *restrict pfTab, float *restrict pfResult,
           int iSize, int iIndex)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
     pfResult[i] = pfResult[i] + pfTab[iIndex];
}
$ gcc -v
...
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC)
$ gcc -std=c99 -O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -c foo.c
foo.c:3: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
foo.c:1: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```

The second version vectorises since the value is transferred to a variable with an automatic storage duration. The general assumption here is that `pfResult` does not span over the stack memory where `fTab` is stored (a cursory read through the C99 language specification doesn't make it clear if that assumption is weak or something in the standard allows it).

The OpenMP version does not vectorise because of the way OpenMP is implemented in GCC. It uses code outlining for the parallel regions.

```
int MyFunc(const float *pfTab, float *pfResult, int iSize, int iIndex)
{
  float fTab =  pfTab[iIndex];
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
     pfResult[i] = pfResult[i] + fTab;
}
```

effectively becomes:

```
struct omp_data_s
{
  float *pfResult;
  int iSize;
  float *fTab;
};

int MyFunc(const float *pfTab, float *pfResult, int iSize, int iIndex)
{
  float fTab =  pfTab[iIndex];
  struct omp_data_s omp_data_o;

  omp_data_o.pfResult = pfResult;
  omp_data_o.iSize = iSize;
  omp_data_o.fTab = fTab;

  GOMP_parallel_start (MyFunc_omp_fn0, &omp_data_o, 0);
  MyFunc._omp_fn.0 (&omp_data_o);
  GOMP_parallel_end ();
  pfResult = omp_data_o.pfResult;
  iSize = omp_data_o.iSize;
  fTab = omp_data_o.fTab;
}

void MyFunc_omp_fn0 (struct omp_data_s *omp_data_i)
{
  int start = ...; // compute starting iteration for current thread
  int end = ...; // compute ending iteration for current thread

  for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    omp_data_i->pfResult[i] = omp_data_i->pfResult[i] + omp_data_i->fTab;
}
```

`MyFunc_omp_fn0` contains the outlined function code. The compiler is not able to prove that `omp_data_i->pfResult` does not point to memory that aliases `omp_data_i` and specifically its member `fTab`.

In order to vectorise that loop, you have to make `fTab` `firstprivate`. This will turn it into an automatic variable in the outlined code and that will be equivalent to your second case:

```
$ cat foo.c
int MyFunc(const float *pfTab, float *pfResult, int iSize, int iIndex)
{
   float fTab = pfTab[iIndex];
   #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(fTab)
   for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
     pfResult[i] = pfResult[i] + fTab;
}
$ gcc -std=c99 -fopenmp -O3 -march=native -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -c foo.c
foo.c:6: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
foo.c:4: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```