# omp_outlined in omp program compiled with LLVM

Tags: llvm, openmp, llvm-clang

When compiling a cpp program with OMP directives using LLVM clang++ 4.9.2 I see hidden function @.omp_outlined. was generated in the bitcode. I wonder what is this hidden function and if it is possible to avoid generating it.

Comment: There is no clang 4.9.2. The latest released version is 3.8

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot prevent the generation of outlined code in Clang. Outlining the parallel region code into its own function is how OpenMP is implemented by Clang and many other compilers, including GCC, Intel, and MSVC. More details on how GCC implements it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18789429/1374437) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046905/1374437). Clang follows more or less the same method.

To my knowledge, the only OpenMP compiler that does not explicitly outline OpenMP parallel regions is the one from PGI. It does some stack frame magic to enable multiple threads to execute portions of the function code.